# Change a buttons action by two other buttons. C#

Tags: c#, button, action

I got three buttons. And have two List strings with random lines. I want to be able to push the two first buttons to change the "action" on the third one. If I click on the first button the third one only uses "HEB" and if I click the second one, the third one uses "HEC"

When pressing button1, I want button3 to do this:

```
HEB f1 = new HEB();
textBox1.Text = f1.RandomString();
```

When pressing button2, I want button3 to do this:

```
HEC f2 = new HEC();
textBox1.Text = f2.RandomString();
```

What is the best way to solve this?

EDIT:
HEB and HEC are random text that is displayed in textbox1 when clicked on button3.

FULL CODE:

```
    namespace Questions
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HEB f1 = new HEB();
        textBox1.Text = f1.RandomString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HEC f2 = new HEC();
        textBox1.Text = f2.RandomString();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        }
    }
}


public class HEB
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>
        {
    "This is test number 1",
    "This is test number 2",
    "This is test number 3"
    };
    public string RandomString()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.Next(list.Count);
        string randomString = list[index];
        return randomString;
    }
}


public class HEC
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>
        {
         "This will show later number 4",
         "This will show later number 5",
         "This will show later number 6",
};
    public string RandomString()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.Next(list.Count);
        string randomString = list[index];
        return randomString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "two-three buttons" (I'm not the downvoter.) 

Please clarify some of the identifiers in your code... HEB, HavamalEB()? What do those do?

Comment: I did uppdate with more information on what I meen. Hope its easier to understand. HavamalEB was an error writing, it is suppose to be HEB and is updated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a list with the current "messages" that you can change to pre-defined values using the first two buttons and then pick a random one of the current messages when pressing the third button.

Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private List<string> messages;

    private string RandomString()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return messages[random.Next(messages.Count)];
    }

//To use it just do:
//(if it is a button it should have a method that it triggers on use)
    private void HEB() 
    {
        //same for HEC, but other strings (test 3 and 4)
        messages = new List<string>(){"test 1", "test 2"}; 
    }

    private void TheButton()
    {
        textBox1.text = RandomString();
    }
}
```

This should work, but don't be afraid to ask for more clarification :)

EDIT: updated code that works (just add the variables and replace the code within your current buttons with the code inside mine).

```
namespace Test_btns
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<string> messages;
        Random random = new Random();

        private string RandomString()
        {
            return messages[random.Next(messages.Count)];
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messages = new List<string>() { "test 1", "test 2" };
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            messages = new List<string>() { "test 3", "test 4" };
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = RandomString();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //not really needed for this, but the method exists.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just updated with more information. I did try your solution but get error with "not a class" when using **byte action = 0;**

Comment: hello, I changed the code based on your feedback and updates. Hope it gives you an idea of how to manage it.

Comment: I did try to add your code but get a lot of errors, with "arg" is not valid. I must say I don't really understand the code when changing how one button will work.

Comment: I think it would be best to show full code instead. Sorry for uppdating again.  Right now button 1 is doing HEB, and button 2 is doing HEC, but I want button3 to use HEB when first pressing button 1 and HEC when I pressed button 2.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the first two buttons to first display a random (out of 3) strings and then the third button to replicate the latest button press (with another random string)? That would also be doable with my code example. Also, is it important that HEC and HEB are classes?

Comment: No, If we say I have two translation on a text danish and swedish. I want to be able to press the swedish button, that will make the "shuffle button" show only the swedish list. If I press danish button, the "shuffle button" will only show the danish list.

Comment: I see, pretty clever. I edited my answer with a code that I tested and that works for swapping the answer on the last by pressing the two first. Should only be needed to copy-paste the code into the program and try it.

Comment: Thank you so mutch. Exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I should ask a new question, but, if I click Button3 without pressing button1 or 2, the program crash. I understand I have to use "If", but in this case, what is best?

Comment: you can just add `private List<string> messages = new List<string>(){"test 1", "test 2"};`
to the beginning of the code. Also, happy to help and glad it worked :)